# Running multiple sites from the same VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, wordpress

How can I, using apache, run two different sites from the same domain?

I have two "parts" of a website that are built in different things. We have some content managed, public facing components made in wordpress and a webapp like section of the site made in laravel. The front page of the site has to hit the wordpress site but there are other parts like "www.xyz.com/design" that need to hit the laravel app.

How can I direct certain URLs to the wordpress site and certain urls to the laravel site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify the htaccess file that comes with Wordpress as by default it rewrites all URLs to a single controller script.

Change the line:

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

With something like the following, which will redirect any URI path that *does not* start with 'design' to the index.php controller script.

```
RewriteRule ^(?!design/).* /index.php [L]
```